# Is it possible to set some columns automatically in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a model with these 2 columns

1. created_at: date
2. last_updated_at: date

Is it possible to set these values automatically whenever a insert or update happens. Or should I be calling a method inside this class to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the *Python-Executed Functions* section of [Column Insert/Update Defaults](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#column-insert-update-defaults) documentation.
Your code will then look similar to the following:

```
# ...
import datetime
# ...
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    # ...
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.date.today)
    last_updated_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
```